# Typesetting a song inside a non-fiction book

Tags: typography, verse

In several places in a book, I need to quote songs. I've tried the `verse` environment, but it doesn't really look great:

```
\begin{verse}
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Tout se tait, l'heure fuit.\\
Seuls Joseph et Marie humblement,\\
sont penchés au berceau de l'Enfant.\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!

Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Rois, bergers vont à Lui.\\
L'air s'emplit de cantiques joyeux,\\
qui s'envolent aux portes des cieux.\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!

Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Où Jésus a souri.\\
Son amour jusqu'à nous est venu!\\
L'âme en Lui trouve enfin le salut!\\
Christ au monde est donné!\\
Christ au monde est donné!

(Traduction Denereaz)
\end{verse}
```

[image: a song typeset using verse]

What would you recommend using to typeset this?

Comment: Did you look at the `verse` package?

Comment: It's what I'm currently using, but it's not looking really great. Maybe I just need to adjust it…

Comment: Ah no, I'm using the verse *environment*, not package :-)

Comment: I don't think there's a "correct" answer to this question. I'd probably add more vertical space before the verses and maybe reduce the indentation or center it with respect to the wider verse (you have centered final quotes in your book); the "(Traduction...)" might be pushed right and in smaller type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like @egreg suggested, the `verse` package can do a much nicer job:

```
\begin{verse}
\begin{altverse}
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Tout se tait, l'heure fuit.\\
Seuls Joseph et Marie humblement,\\
sont penchés au berceau de l'Enfant.\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Rois, bergers vont à Lui.\\
L'air s'emplit de cantiques joyeux,\\
qui s'envolent aux portes des cieux.\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Où Jésus a souri.\\
Son amour jusqu'à nous est venu!\\
L'âme en Lui trouve enfin le salut!\\
Christ au monde est donné!\\
Christ au monde est donné!
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}
\attrib{Traduction: Denereaz}
```

[image: using the verse package]

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using the [songs](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{}[by={(Traduction Denereaz)}]
\beginverse
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Tout se tait, l'heure fuit.\\
Seuls Joseph et Marie humblement,\\
sont penchés au berceau de l'Enfant.\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!
\endverse

\beginverse
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Rois, bergers vont à Lui.\\
L'air s'emplit de cantiques joyeux,\\
qui s'envolent aux portes des cieux.\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!
\endverse

\beginverse
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Où Jésus a souri.\\
Son amour jusqu'à nous est venu!\\
L'âme en Lui trouve enfin le salut!\\
Christ au monde est donné!\\
Christ au monde est donné!
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}


\end{document}
```

[image]

You can easily turn off numbering and suppress the rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\nosongnumbers
\setlength\sbarheight{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{}[by={(Traduction Denereaz)}]
\beginverse
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Tout se tait, l'heure fuit.\\
Seuls Joseph et Marie humblement,\\
sont penchés au berceau de l'Enfant.\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!\\
Dors, Jésus radieux!
\endverse

\beginverse
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Rois, bergers vont à Lui.\\
L'air s'emplit de cantiques joyeux,\\
qui s'envolent aux portes des cieux.\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!\\
C'est Jésus le Sauveur!
\endverse

\beginverse
Douce nuit! Sainte nuit!\\
Où Jésus a souri.\\
Son amour jusqu'à nous est venu!\\
L'âme en Lui trouve enfin le salut!\\
Christ au monde est donné!\\
Christ au monde est donné!
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is nice indeed, but I wouldn't like to have the big 1 and the hrules then, which are specifically made to typeset a song book, which is not my case.

Comment: @ℝaphink Please see my updated answer.

Comment: OK. The syntax looks like a mix of LaTeX and ConTeXt to me ;-)

Comment: Also, the `song` package is not on a CTAN.